# How to prevent URL blind sql injection attack

Tags: php, sql-injection

I have a website which is online ,i am using acunetix for checking web vulnerabilities in my website. while scanning using acunetix it showed a high risk alert in url blind sql injection.(i am not putting the code due to its long length)

eg :url showing vuln

```
   www.site.com/phpfile.php?1d=1
```

i am using mysql_real_escape_string function ;after this also its showing high risk alert. how do i prevent it...

and if any one new can you please tell me how i can hide(with out using .htacess; in my server .htacess is not working) the ?id=1

eg: when the user clicks the query it should show this

```
   www.site.com/phpfile.php
```

instead of

```
   www.site.com/phpfile.php?1d=1
```

Pardon my english and advance thanks for the help

Comment: Do not use the answer you accepted! It does *not* protect you from actual attacks! Malicious users can easily modify what is sent via POST!

Answer (score 3):

You should escape strings using `mysql_real_escape_string()`, but when the expected input is an integer it never helps (if the user input isn't quoted in the query, it won't really make any difference) - you should cast it to an integer instead, either using `(int)` or the `intval()` function.

Also, I highly recommended you to work with prepared statements (e.g. [PDO](http://php.net/pdo/)) or an ORM layer (e.g. [Doctrine](http://doctrine-project.org)).

Comment: The only sane answer here. Edited the wording though.

Answer (score 2):

> if any one new can you please tell me how i can hide the ?id=1

There is absolutely no point in that.
Hiding adds nothing to security.
And viewing user's profile should be done with GET method, not POST.

> i am using mysql_real_escape_string function

This function has nothing to do with injections. It is called not "mysql_prevent_injection", but "mysql_real_escape_string". So, it is used merely to format strings. And have to be used for strings only.
If you want to treat your data as a string, you have to put it in quotes. So, mysql would know it's a string.
One have always use these 2 things together - quotes and escaping. They are useless one without another.

If you don't want to treat your number as a string, format it as a number.

```
$id = intval($_GET['id']);
```

You have to format every part of the string according to it's type, not just use some functions at random.

Answer (score -2):

If you know that your id should be a number you can use:

```
if(is_numeric($_GET['id'])){
    $id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
}
else{
    ;///////display error
}
```

Comment: What? what mysql_real_escape_string is for here?

Comment: `mysql_real_escape_string` is completely useless here. It does literally nothing, because you've already done what you should do, and tested for a numeric value.

Answer (score -3):

You can easily hide the `?id=1` using a `POST` request instead of a `GET`